# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}$$

*Attempt*

Consider $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp(\log(\frac{a^n}{n!}))=\exp\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(n\log(a)-\sum_{n\geq 1}\log(n)\right)\right)$$

for $a>1$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(n\log(a)\right)=\infty $$
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1}\log(n)\leq \int_{1}^{\infty}{\log(x)dx}=\infty$$

therefore $$\exp\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(n\log(a)-\sum_{n\geq 1}\log(n)\right)\right)=\exp(-\infty)=0$$
therefore

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=0$$
Is my proof right?

I think that is not general, since $a>1$ and in the problem $a$ is arbitrary

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: My proof is right?,

Comment: Are you assuming from the outset that the limit actually exists?

Comment: Your sum index is $n$. Not good. Choose $k$ and let the upper bound for the sum be $n$.

Comment: Not, because the limit exists iff the other series of limits exists

Comment: The line after the first "therefore" is not valid.

Comment: I see the mistake, since i get $\infty-\infty$

Comment: The line after consider is not valid. You defined $n$ as a limit variable but now it is also a sum index??

Comment: Exists a form of do it,without a lot of inequalities?

Comment: HINT: $$\left|{a^n\over n!}\right|\le k {|a|\over n}$$ for large enough $n$, where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: yes, can mark it like a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replying to your last comment: Yes there is a faster way. Show that for sufficiently large $n$ the following inequality holds:
$$n!>(a+1)^n.$$
We now have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^n}{(a+1)^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^n \to 0.$$

Comment: It´s a nice proof

Comment: it´s relation with binomial expression since $a^n=(1+(a-1))^n$?

Comment: I don't understand. What is your question? Your equality is right but why is it important?

Comment: exists a relation between $n!> (a+1)^n$ and the expression above?

Comment: Ohh. There is a nice way to think about it. I will show it for $a=1$. You have to prove it then for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. $$1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots(n-1)\cdot n > \underbrace{2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdots2\cdot2}_{\text{$n$ times}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! for the idea

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

It seems you are working with $a>1$, although it is not stated at the beginning but rather in the middle. I will go with that assumption:

$a^n>0$ and $n! > 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now,

> $\displaystyle \frac{a^n}{n!} = \frac{a\cdot a \cdots a}{1\cdot 2 \cdots n} $

At some point we will have $n > a$, say this occurs at $N$, take $n > N$ then

> $\displaystyle \frac{a^n}{n!} = \frac{a\cdot a \cdots a}{1\cdot 2 \cdots n}  \le \frac{a \cdots a}{1 \cdots (N-1)}\cdot \frac{a \cdots a}{N \cdots n} \le  \frac{a^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}\cdot \frac{a^{n-(N-1)}}{N\cdots n}$

Now, since we have $m > a, \forall m \in \{N,\ldots,n\}$ we know $\displaystyle \frac{a}{m} < 1$

Hence

> $\displaystyle \frac{a^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}\cdot \frac{a^{n-(N-1)}}{N\cdots n} \le \frac{a^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}\cdot \frac{a}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Nice answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Starting from your idea, try to find the limit of $n log(a) - \sum_{k=1}^n log(k)$. Then apply what you know about the $exp$ function.

Comment: The exponential function separe the product

Comment: And tends to 0 at $-\infty$.